# If rank(XY) = rank(X), show that the column space C(XY) = C(X)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

My attempt:

rank(XY) = dim(C(XY))

rank(X) = dim(C(X))

Therefore, dim(C(XY)) = dim(C(X))

Therefore, C(XY) is a subset of C(X)

Therefore, C(XY) = C(X)

Comment: I did see that before posting this, but I wasn't sure if I was missing a logical step in between saying that the column space of XY is a subset of the column space of X and then claiming that C(XY) = C(X).

Comment: You are misusing the word "therefore", which is making the argument hard to read. When you say that the column space of $XY$ is a subset of the column space for $X$, it is not following from the previous line, so it is not appropriate to say "Therefore,...". You need to explain in a basic way why the columns space inclusion holds.

Comment: There is indeed a missing step in your argument: the subset claim isn't because of the the equal dimensions. But the column spaces are equal *because of the subset relation and the equal dimensions*.

Comment: So, using the explanation in the link to the other post, I think that in order to show that the column space of XY is a subset of the column space of X I need to first state that any column in XY is a linear combination of the columns in X. And since their dimensions are the same, then their column spaces are now shown to be the same, correct?

Comment: Yeah that's an argument that works. I don't know what level of detail you need to give in the explanation, that depends on context of the question, but basically that is an argument that works. (Alternative argument: If you know that the column space is the range of the linear map that the matrices define then it is even easier to argue for the inclusion.)

Comment: I think that level of detail would likely suffice for this one. Thank you for the help, T_M and prets. Much appreciated.